# How to get every Nth element of an infinite list in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

More specifically, how do I generate a new list of every Nth element from an existing infinite list?

E.g. if the list is `[5, 3, 0, 1, 8, 0, 3, 4, 0, 93, 211, 0 ...]` then getting every 3rd element would result in this list `[0,0,0,0,0 ...]`

Answer (score 61, accepted):

My version using drop:

```
every n xs = case drop (n-1) xs of
              y : ys -> y : every n ys
              [] -> []
```

Edit: this also works for finite lists.  For infinite lists only, Charles Stewart's solution is slightly shorter.

Comment: I would be inclined to name this `takeEvery` or `takeNth`; unfortunately, both of those in various other languages refer to a version that always includes the first element and only starts skipping N thereafter.  Not sure how best to distinguish those intents in the name.

Comment: Deciphering session would be great. What [] -> [] does?

Comment: @kaboom `[] -> []` is using pattern matching to return an empty list when `drop (n-1) xs` returns an empty list.

Comment: I would also like to add that the two patterns of this function should be switched for a properly formatted tail call.  So `[] -> []` should come before `(y:ys) -> y : every n ys`.

Comment: I'm still fresh with Haskell, this is melting my brain. But I shall not stop trying :) Thanks for the answers!

Comment: @VictorJohnson this is not Prolog. the first pattern that matches, fires, and its body is in tail position then. If I'm mistaken, I'd appreciate being pointed as to why.

Comment: @WillNess I agree with you. IIRC I was referring more to formatting than how it will be compiled and optimized (though that comment was over a year and a half ago, so I can't recall exactly what "properly formatted" means)

Comment: @VictorJohnson it is tail any which way this is formatted though. :)

Comment: How would you implement a similar solution without using 'drop' ? Is it possible to have a function that takes a list and constructs a new list with every nth element  and have the function operate in linear time?

Comment: @Kaylo I think all the answers with drop are linear time, no? Anyway, posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57480917/204723)  that doesn't use drop and is linear time.

Answer (score 37):

All the solutions using `zip` and so on do tons of unnecessary allocations.  As a functional programmer, you want to get into the habit of not allocating unless you really have to.  Allocation is expensive, and compared to allocation, everything else is free.  And allocation doesn't just show up in the "hot spots" you would find with a profiler; if you don't pay attention to allocation, it kills you *everywhere*.

Now I agree with the commentators that **readability is the most important thing**.  Nobody wants to get wrong answers fast.  But it happens very often in functional programming that there are multiple solutions, all about equally readable, some of which allocate and some of which do not.  It's really important to build a habit of looking for those *readable, non-allocating* solutions.

You might think that the optimizer would get rid of allocations, but you'd only be half right.  GHC, the world's best optimizing compiler for Haskell, does manage to avoid allocating a pair per element; it fuses the `filter`-`zip` composition into a `foldr2`.  The allocation of the list `[1..]` remains.  Now you might not think this is so bad, but stream fusion, which is GHC's current technology, is a somewhat fragile optimization.  It's hard even for experts to predict exactly when it's going to work, just by looking at the code.  The more general point is that **when it comes to a critical property like allocation, you don't want to rely on a fancy optimizer whose results you can't predict**.  As long as you can write your code in an equally readable way, you're much better off never introducing those allocations.

For these reason I find  Nefrubyr's solution using `drop` to be by far the most compelling.  The only values that are allocated are exactly those cons cells (with `:`) that *must* be part of the final answer.  Added to that, the use of `drop` makes the solution more than just easy to read: it is crystal clear and obviously correct.

Comment: I agree, and I find Nefrubyr's solution easier to follow as well.

Comment: I'm sure a good compiler will avoid the unnessary allocations.

Comment: -1, i would recommend coding for readability then profiling then optimizing the profiled portions. No point in making  code readability sacrifices when it may not even cause a problem

Comment: sth's version has this property too.

Comment: @trinithis: I checked with GHC, and you are mostly right.  But you make a good point, so I have edited my answer to make it clear why you don't necessarily want to throw an optimizer at some code and hope for the best.

Comment: @RCIX: I agree with you, but only in part.  Certainly readability is paramount.   But if you ignore allocation *everywhere*, then you will slow down *all* of your program, and there won't necessarily be "hot spots" that you can find easily by profiling.   I've updated my asnwer to try to reflect a more nuanced view.

Comment: Wrt. readability: it is not only about knowing how inouts are transformed into outputs, it is also about knowing how the machine will do this.  Prolog is lovely for making it clear what problem is being solved.  But acquiring a feel for what happens when you run the code...

Comment: 3 upvotes on the -1 comment but only one actual downvote. hehe. great answer, long ago upvoted; just one comment: when good non-allocating code becomes less readable, it is good to keep a clear, concise, allocating variant around as a comment, an executable specification if you will.

Comment: I think the readability is subjective. Most of people don't think Haskell is easy to read at all. To me, as long as we understand the code, we can aim for less allocation, so agree to the author.

Answer (score 16):

I don't have anything to test this with at work, but something like:

```
extractEvery m = map snd . filter (\(x,y) -> (mod x m) == 0) . zip [1..]
```

should work even on infinite lists.

(Edit: tested and corrected.)

Comment: Thanks, this works well, although I don't quite understand it yet (I'm still a beginner in Haskell).

Comment: doing lots of work with predictable results... never do this in real code.

Answer (score 14):

Starting at the first element:

```
everyf n [] = []
everyf n as  = head as : everyf n (drop n as)
```

Starting at the nth element:

```
every n = everyf n . drop (n-1)
```

Comment: Taking this to the logical next step, `everyf n = map head . takeWhile (not . null) . iterate (drop n)` or `every n = map head . takeWhile (not . null) . iterate (drop n) . drop (n-1)`.

Comment: `. drop (n-1)` instead of `(drop (n-1) as)` makes it so much nicer and more readable that I now just had to use that in my answer... :)

Comment: Very nice. I like how you gave two functions to get either [0, N1, N2, N3...] or [N1, N2, N3...].

Answer (score 14):

The compiler or interpreter will compute the step size (subtract 1 since it's zero based):

```
f l n = [l !! i | i <- [n-1,n-1+n..]]
```

[The Haskell 98 Report: Arithmetic Sequences](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#arithmetic-sequences)

Comment: This one has by-far the best Golf score but no upvotes. There's no justice.

Comment: I don't really care about golf score but this is a really neat solution for infinite lists. Should be noted it doesn't work on finite lists though.

Comment: @phunehehe no, it is a terrible solution, because it re-traverses the list from the start and so has *quadratic* behaviour; and causes `l`'s retention in memory - prevents `l` from being garbage collected, from being made ephemeral and not being allocated at all.

Answer (score 11):

MHarris's answer is great. But I like to avoid using `\`, so here's my golf:

```
extractEvery n
  = map snd . filter fst
  . zip (cycle (replicate (n-1) False ++ [True]))
```

Comment: Or `cycle $ replicate (n-1) False ++ [True]` since OP wants to start at index `n-1`, not index `0`.

Comment: Yes, ephemient's modification does what I originally asked for.

Answer (score 10):

Alternate solution to get rid of `mod`:

```
extractEvery n = map snd . filter ((== n) . fst) . zip (cycle [1..n])
```

Comment: `mod`, `==`, what's the difference? still doing tests with predictable results... I don't think you'd code it like this, today. :)

Answer (score 10):

I nuked my version of Haskell the other day, so untested, but the following seems a little simpler than the others (leverages pattern matching and drop to avoid zip and mod):

```
everynth :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
everynth n xs = y : everynth n ys
         where y : ys = drop (n-1) xs
```

Comment: I started with this, and then tested it: it fails for finite lists when (y:ys) cannot match the empty list.  But the question is for infinite lists so I guess that's OK!

Comment: Indeed, this works fine for infinite lists, but not for finite lists. I like how simple the solution looks -- if only it worked for finite lists as well...

Comment: The failure of this to work for finite lists hints that the version that keeps every element whose index is a multiple of n is more 'natural'.

Answer (score 5):

Another way of doing it:

```
takeEveryM m lst = [n | (i,n) <- zip [1..] lst, i `mod` m == 0]
```

Yet Another:

```
import Data.List

takeEveryMth m = 
  (unfoldr g)  . dr
     where 
       dr = drop (m-1)
       g (x:xs) = Just (x, dr xs)
       g []     = Nothing
```

Answer (score 3):

Explicit recursion is evil! Use a library construct like map, filter, fold, scan, reproduce, iterate etc instead. Unless it makes the code drastically easier to read even to those au fait with the libraries, then it's just making your code less modular, more verbose and harder to reason about.

Seriously, the explicitly recursive versions need to be voted down to negative for a task as simple as this. Now I guess I should say something constructive to balance my carping.

I prefer to use a map:

```hs
every n xs = map (xs!!) [n-1,n-1+n..]
```

rather than the ja's list comprehension so the reader doesn't have to worry about what i is. But either way it's O(n^2) when it could be O(n), so maybe this is better:

```hs
every n = map (!!(n-1)) . iterate (drop n)
```

Comment: I did try to rewrite my answer as a map or fold but in this case I found the explicit recursion cleanest.  As a general principle I agree with you that library functions such as maps and folds are preferred.  primodemus's answer using unfoldr is the sort of thing I was aiming for, but I'm glad I stopped where I did ;-)  Your solution walks each section of the list twice (once for `!!`, once for `drop`); ephemient's comment on sth's answer gives the best solution along these lines by "sliding" the list along and using `map head`.

Comment: Missed that comment! Was a toss-up whether to post that or mine, decided simpler code was more important than a constant factor.

People frequently do find explicit recursion clearer before they're used to the libraries, but the way to get used to the libraries is to use them. Voting up explicitly-recursive solutions to something like this is a good way to _prevent_ them learning to do it right.

Answer (score 2):

Use a view pattern!

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

everynth n (drop (n-1) -> l)
  | null l = []
  | otherwise = head l : everynth n (tail l)
```

---

Ugly version of Nefrubyr's answer preserved so comments make sense.

```
everynth :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
everynth n l = case splitAt (n-1) l of
                 (_, (x:xs)) -> x : everynth n xs
                 _           -> []
```

Comment: Seems rather pointless to use `splitAt` instead of `drop` if you never even look at the `fst` of the resulting tuple.

Comment: I see now that it's a muddier version of Nefrubyr's answer.

Comment: Go ahead and remove it if you want; anybody confused can look through edit history, or I can delete my comment.  That aside: documentation for `ViewPatterns` says that the implementation shall tries to gather common views together for execution efficiency, so I think the guards are just confounding.  Subjective, of course...

Comment: Maybe it'll spare someone thinking, 'No one's used `splitAt` yet!' I agree that the guards aren't ideal, but the alternatives aren't great either: I'd have to repeat the same code in separate cases or define a helper function at the outer scope—nicer if cases of a function could share a `where` clause.

Answer (score 1):

`extractEvery n l = map head (iterate (drop n) (drop (n-1) l))`

I was going to feel proud of myself, until I saw that Greg got about the same answer and before me

Answer (score 1):

A lot of answers here already use Data.List.unfoldr, but I wanted to bring up an interesting way of writing the somewhat annoying unfold that may be helpful in other contexts:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}
import Data.List (unfoldr)
import Data.Maybe (listToMaybe)

every n = unfoldr f . drop (n - 1)
    where f xs = (,drop n xs) <$> listToMaybe xs
```

When the list is null, `listToMaybe` returns a `Nothing`, and `fmap` similarly will then be `Nothing`. However, if a `Just` is produced, then the proper tuple is constructed by turning the head of the list into a tuple of the head and the rest of the values to use in the next iteration.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly silly version with `foldr`:

```
everyNth n l = foldr cons nil l (n-1) where
  nil _ = []
  cons x rest 0 = x : rest n
  cons x rest n = rest (n-1)
```

Comment: Not silly in the least! This should be able to fuse with a "good producer" to (potentially) avoid realizing the argument list. I imagine you could wrap `GHC.List.build` around this to make it fuse the other way too.

Comment: You can probably also make it take any foldable, rather than insisting on a list.

Answer (score 1):

(This was in response to [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026912/how-to-get-every-nth-element-of-an-infinite-list-in-haskell/57480917#comment91691860_2028218) asking for a solution without drop)

I couldn't see this solution, so:

```hs
every _ []     = []
every n (x:xs) = every' n (n-1) (x:xs)
                 where every' n c []     = []
                       every' n 0 (x:xs) = x : every' n (n-1) xs
                       every' n c (x:xs) = every' n (c-1) xs
```

works for finite and infinite list:

```hs
take 15 (every 3 [1..])
-- [3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45]
```

Comment: @WillNess yes, but the comment asked for a solution without drop :-D I considered doing a fold, but that felt out of the spirit of the challenge.

Comment: Great ! Note that you don't need `n` as a leftmost parameter of your `every'` function, as it is constant and provided by the outer scope.

Comment: No need for the outer matching. Just `every n = every' n (n-1)`, or, as @jpmarinier points out, even `every n = every' (n-1)`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems a slightly better use of unfold:

```
everyNth :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
everyNth n = unfoldr g
  where
    g [] = Nothing
    g xs = let (ys, zs) = splitAt n xs in Just (head ys, zs)
```

Or even better, use Data.List.Spit:

```
everyNth n = (map head) . chunksOf n
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I'll post what I came up with:

```
everyNth :: [a] -> Int -> [a]
everyNth xs n = [snd x | x <- (zip [1..] xs), fst x `mod` n == 0]
```

I put the list argument before the `Int` so I can curry the function and a list then map that over a list of `Int`s if ever I need to.

Answer (score 0):

It's more elegant to solve a related problem first: Keep every element whose index is divisible by n.

```
everyNth n [] = []
everyNth n (x:xs) = x : (everyNth n . drop (n-1)) xs
```

And then to solve the example, use

```
everyNthFirst n = everyNth n . drop (n-1)
```

`everyNthFirst 3 [5, 3, 0, 1, 8, 0, 3, 4, 0, 93, 211, 0 ...]` gives `[0, 0, 0, ...]`

Comment: Hmm I get  ```Prelude> everyNthFirst 3 $ take 10 [1..]
[3,7*** Exception: <interactive>:2:1-48: Non-exhaustive patterns in function everyNth``` in GHCi (ghc 8.4.3). Compiling into a short program though, I get `[2,6,10,14,18,22,26,30,34,38,42,46]` if I do `putStrLn $ show $ everyNthFirst 3 $ take 50 $ [0..]`. The correct behavior should instead be `[2, 5, 8, 11, ...]` right?

Comment: Thanks.  I fixed the bug, should work.  If you want to try in ghci, put both equations of the definition on one line separated by semicolon ; otherwise you define two functions, with the second shadowing the first.

Answer (score 0):

`Data.List.HT` from `utility-ht` has `sieve :: Int -> [a] -> [a]`.

See [documentation](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.19/utility-ht-0.0.14/Data-List-HT.html#v:sieve) and [source](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.19/utility-ht-0.0.14/src/Data.List.HT.Private.html#sieve):

```
{-| keep every k-th value from the list -}
sieve, sieve', sieve'', sieve''' :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
sieve k =
   unfoldr (\xs -> toMaybe (not (null xs)) (head xs, drop k xs))

sieve' k = map head . sliceVertical k

sieve'' k x = map (x!!) [0,k..(length x-1)]

sieve''' k = map head . takeWhile (not . null) . iterate (drop k)

propSieve :: Eq a => Int -> [a] -> Bool
propSieve n x =
   sieve n x == sieve'  n x   &&
   sieve n x == sieve'' n x
```

Answer (score 0):

And a very functional one without apparent conditionals:

```
everyNth :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
everyNth 0 = take 1
everyNth n = foldr ($) [] . zipWith ($) operations where
  operations = cycle $ (:) : replicate (n-1) (const id)
```

(Note, this one takes every element whose index is a multiple of n.  Which is slightly different from the original question, but easy to convert.)

Answer (score 0):

We can use a list comprehension:

```
takeEvery :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
takeEvery n xs = [x | (x, i) <- zip xs [1..], i `mod` n == 0]
```

From all value-index pairs (x, i), take x if i is divisible by n. Note that the index starts from one here.

Answer (score -1):

My solution is:

```
every :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
every _ [] = []
every n list = take n list : (every n $ drop n list)
```

It do not use zip but I can't tell about it's performances and memory profile.

Comment: This code does not work. E.g. `every 3 [1,2,3,4,5,6]` yields `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`

Answer (score -1):

An uglier, and more limited version of the accepted answer

```
every :: Eq a => Int -> [a] -> [a]
every n xs = if rest == [] 
                then [] 
                else head rest : every n (tail rest)
    where rest = drop (n-1) xs
```

For "line golfing" it can be written like this:

```
every n xs = if rest == [] then [] else head rest : every n (tail rest) 
    where rest = drop (n-1) xs
```

(It's more limited because it has an unnecessary `Eq a` constraint.)

Comment: What's the point in contributing an uglier version of an accepted answer? To appreciate the accepted answer more? :-)

Comment: Ugly functions need love, too ;).