# How to create infinitely repeating list in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, lazy-evaluation

I'm a C# guy trying to teach myself Haskell from Erik Meijer's Channel 9 webcasts. I came across an interesting puzzle which involved skipping every 'n' elements of a list using zip and mod.

```
every :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
every _ [] = []
every n xs = [x | (x,i) <- zip xs [1..], i `mod` n == 0]
```

I've been thinking it might be more efficient (for really large lists, or streams) if we could avoid using mod.

I thought about lazily creating a repeating list of integers so we can simply compare the value of i to n.

```
repeatInts :: Int -> [Int]
```

such that calling `repeatInts 3` returns `[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,..]` ad infinitum.

Given this, we could redefine `every` like so:

```
every :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
every _ [] = []
every n xs = [x | (x,i) <- zip xs (repeatInts n), i == n]
```

So my questions is: how would you implement `repeatInts`?

Comment: Cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026912/how-to-get-every-nth-element-of-an-infinite-list-in-haskell

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use [`cycle`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:cycle):

> ```
> cycle :: [a] -> [a]
> ```
>
> `cycle` ties a finite list into a circular one, or equivalently, the infinite repetition of the original list. It is the identity on infinite lists.

You could define `repeatInts` in terms of `cycle`:

```
*Main> let repeatInts n = cycle [1..n]
*Main> :t repeatInts
repeatInts :: (Num t, Enum t) => t -> [t]
*Main> take 10 $ repeatInts 3
[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1]
```

---

For the curious, GHC implements `cycle` with

```
cycle [] = errorEmptyList "cycle"
cycle xs = xs' where xs' = xs ++ xs'
```

In purely functional parlance, this curious technique is known as *tying the knot*, and it creates cyclic data structures rather than infinite ones.

For details see

- [“Tying the Knot”](https://wiki.haskell.org/Tying_the_Knot) on the Haskell wiki
- [“Tying the knot”](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Compiler/TyingTheKnot) in GHC’s commentary
- [“Explanation of ‘tying the knot’”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/357956/123109) here on Stack Overflow
- Stack Overflow tag [`[tying-the-knot]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tying-the-knot)

Comment: Thanks, gbacon. Somehow I knew there'd be a simple answer! Now I can dig into the workings of `cycle`.

Comment: Somewhat strangely, `cycle` is standard Haskell '98, even though cyclic lists are not.  See what the source (above) says about it - you might or might not get a cyclic list...

Comment: funnily, this Q/A is itself an instance of the XY problem. ;) skipping every nth element in a list shouldn't involve any `mod`, nor counting to infinity. the proper solution seems to be with either `zip` with `(cycle $ (0 <$ [2..n]) ++
 [1])`, or  via `iterate` with `splitAt`. :)

Answer (score 4):

Late answer but it can also be written like this:

```
repeatInts :: Int -> [Int]
repeatInts 0 = []
repeatInts a = [1..a] ++ repeatInts a
```