# Haskell: split even and odd elements into tuple

Tags: haskell

I can't use high order functions. I just can't see to figure out how to do this. I am very new to haskell. It also has to be recursive.

```
split :: [Int] -> ([Int],[Int])
split xs =
```

I am given this to start with. I honestly don't even know where to start with this problem.

Examples:

```
split []
([],[])

split [1]
([1],[])

split [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
([1,3,5,7,9],[2,4,6,8,10])
```

any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: Its even and odd positions.

So

split [3,6,8,9,10] would be
([3,8,10],[6,9])

ok so i came up with this. Its not pretty, but it seems to work ok.

```
split :: [Int] -> ([Int],[Int])
split [] = ([],[])
split [xs] = ([xs],[])
split xs = (oddlist xs, evenlist xs)

oddlist :: [Int] -> ([Int])
oddlist xs | length xs <= 2 = [head(xs)]
           | otherwise = [head(xs)] ++ oddlist(tail(tail(xs)))

evenlist :: [Int] -> ([Int])
evenlist xs | length xs <= 3 = [head(tail(xs))]
            | otherwise = [head(tail(xs))] ++ evenlist(tail(tail(xs)))
```

Comment: Your example is a bit ambiguous, do you mean elements at even and odd positions, or integers that are themselves even or odd? A better example might be: `split [1,3,2,5,8]` ~> `([1,3,5], [2,8])`

Comment: Oh yea sorry, elements at even and odd positions.

Comment: @Tom hey thanks. Did not notice that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
split [] = ([], [])
split [x] = ([x], [])
split (x:y:xs) = (x:xp, y:yp) where (xp, yp) = split xs
```

Comment: Your signature is slightly off …

Comment: @Konrad: I don't know what you mean. The two `???` are not the same, and I have ignored 2 base cases.

Comment: forget it … I’m apparently out of touch with Haskell for too long. See original answer by me: missing parentheses around list constructor.

Comment: @Konrad: Right, a function taking a single argument is never curried ;-)

Answer (score 6):

If you relax the "no higher-order functions" restriction, you can do it like this:

```
split :: [a] -> ([a],[a])
split = foldr (\x ~(y2,y1) -> (x:y1, y2)) ([],[])
```

Note the `~` makes the pattern match lazy, so `split` can produce results on demand, rather than needing to inspect the entire list first.

You can reimpose the restriction by expanding the `foldr`:

```
split :: [a] -> ([a],[a])
split [] = ([],[])
split (x : xs) = (x : y1, y2)
  where
    (y2, y1) = split xs
```

Comment: I fixed the swapped result, and made things lazy in the expected fashion.

Answer (score 3):

If you’re not allowed to use higher-order list functions, your alternative is basically to use recursion.

The examples already give the cases that you need to cater to:

```
-- Base case:
split [] = …

-- Recurrence:
split (x : xs) = (do something with x) … (split xs) …
```

Comment: Note that @Kenny’s and my solution solve different problems. As @Tom has commented below your question, it’s not clear which of the two solutions suits your exact problem since your example is ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

Since you've put your solution up now, this is how I would implement it:

```
split xs = (everyother 0 xs, everyother 1 xs)
      where everyother _ []     = []
            everyother 1 (x:xs) = everyother 0 xs
            everyother 0 (x:xs) = x : (everyother 1 xs)
```

This implies that the first item in a list is item 0.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is related to [Get every Nth element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026912/how-to-get-every-nth-element-of-an-infinite-list-in-haskell).

Anyway, this is what I would do:

```
ghci> let split ys = let skip xs = case xs of { [] -> [] ; [x] -> [x] ; (x:_:xs') -> x : skip xs' } in (skip ys, skip . drop 1 $ ys)
ghci> split [1..10]
([1,3,5,7,9],[2,4,6,8,10])
```

Or nicely formatted:

```
split xs = (skip xs, skip . drop 1 $ xs)
  where 
  skip [] = []
  skip [x] = [x]
  skip (x:_:xs') = x : skip xs'
```