# Spliting a list in Haskell with fold?

Tags: list, haskell, split, fold

Need to implement a split with `foldl` or `foldr`.

For example: split `[2, 4, 6, 8, 7]` into `([2, 6, 7], [4, 8])`.

Comment: Voting as unclear what you're asking because it's unclear what you're asking. You should at minimum include a description of the problem you're having as well as what your attempts to solve it so far were.

Comment: this question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707753/haskell-split-even-and-odd-elements-into-tuple

Answer (score 2):

This is relatively straight-forward. We know the type of our "seed" for the fold, it must be a pair of lists. We alternate which list of the two lists we're appending to by simply swapping the two lists, and we append to list on the left (which will change between each iteration).

```
foldr (\x (ys,zs) -> (x:zs, ys)) ([],[]) [2,4,6,8,7]  -- ([2,6,7],[4,8])
```

If we were to use `foldl` the lists would come out backwards, so `foldr` seems like the logical choice.

Comment: I guess we can generalise it to something like
`insertAndSwap x (xss,[]) = insertAndSwap x ([],reverse xss)` `insertAndSwap x (yss,(zs:zss)) = ((x:zs):yss, zss)`
`split n | n > 0 = (\(x,y) -> x ++ reverse y) . foldr swap ([], replicate n [])`

Comment: Do you want just want the same thing with triples? `foldr (\x (l1,l2,l3) -> (x:l2,l3,l1)) ([],[],[])`? I think I'm missing something.

Comment: `foldr (\x (l1,l2,l3) -> (x:l3,l1,l2)) ([],[],[]) [1..10]` then. By "missing something" I mean that I have no clue why you're asking the question.

Answer (score 1):

Given a predicate `p :: a -> Bool` you can split on that using `foldr` as follows:

```
split :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a],[a])
split p = foldr (\x (as, bs) -> if p x then (x:as, bs) else (as, x:bs)) ([],[])
```

For example:

```
Prelude> split (\x -> x `mod` 4 /= 0) [2,4,6,8,7]
([2,6,7],[4,8])
```