# How to select every n-th element from a list

Tags: haskell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get every Nth element of an infinite list in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026912/how-to-get-every-nth-element-of-an-infinite-list-in-haskell)

Simple task - we have a list and want to leave only each nth element in that list.
What is the most idiomatic way to do it in haskell?

off the top of my head it is something like:

```
dr n [] = []
dr n (x : xs) = x : (dr n $ drop n xs)
```

but I have a strong feeling that I'm overcomplicating the problem.

Comment: that looks pretty idiomatic to me.

Comment: don't think you will get this any cheaper - looks fine to me. The only point is that this don't fit well to your description as `dr k [1..]` don't yield your questions sequence.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your solution is fine, but here are three other solutions using functions from Haskell's base library.

```
dr1 m = concatMap (take 1) . iterate (drop m)
```

Of coarse, this will never terminate (because `iterate` never terminates).  So perhaps a better solution would be to use `unfoldr`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}
import Data.Maybe
dr2 m = unfoldr ((\x-> fmap (,drop m x) (listToMaybe x)))
```

The function you pass to an unfold can get a bit ugly if you don't know GHC extensions and concepts such as functors, here's that solution again without the fancy foot-work (untested):

```
dr2 m = unfoldr ((\x -> case listToMaybe x of
                         Nothing -> Nothing
                         Just i  -> Just (i,drop m x)))
```

If you don't like unfolds then consider a zip and a filter:

```
dr3 m = map snd . filter ((== 1) . fst) . zip (cycle [1..m])
```

**Review**

Understand all these solutions are slightly different.  Learning why will make you a better Haskell progammer.  `dr1` uses iterate and will thus never terminate (perhaps this is ok for infinite lists, but probably not a good overall solution):

```
> dr1 99 [1..400]
[1,100,199,298,397^CInterrupted.
```

The `dr2` solution will show every `m`th value by skipping values in the unfold.  The unfold passes both the value to be used for the next unfolding and the result of the current unfolding in a single tuple.

```
> dr2 99 [1..400]
[1,100,199,298,397]
```

The `dr3` solution is slightly longer but probably easier for a beginner to understand.  First you tag every element in the list with a cycle of `[1..n, 1..n, 1..n ...]`.  Second, you select only the numbers tagged with a `1`, effectively skipping `n-1` of the elements.  Third you remove the tags.

```
> dr3 99 [1..400]
[1,100,199,298,397]
```

Comment: Thomas, thank you very much. It is very important to know all the ways you can perform relatively simple tasks, and you've just gave me some new ideas.

Answer (score 14):

My variant would be:

```
each :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
each n = map head . takeWhile (not . null) . iterate (drop n)
```

Fast and plays well with laziness.

Comment: yes, it is very nice.  I didn't want to get into discussing laziness (and honestly didn't consider adding a null guard) but this is a good alternative to my broken first example.

Answer (score 8):

Lots of ways to shave this yak! Here's yet another:

```
import Data.List.Split -- from the "split" package on Hackage
dr n = map head . chunk n
```

Comment: chunk is implemented very alike, actually `-- | split at regular intervals
chunk :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
chunk _ [] = [[]]
chunk n xs = y1 : chunk n y2
  where
    (y1, y2) = splitAt n xs`

Comment: @shabunc You bet! Code reuse is the name of the game.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
getEach :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
getEach _ [] = []
getEach n list
 | n < 1     = []
 | otherwise = foldr (\i acc -> list !! (i - 1):acc) [] [n, (2 * n)..(length list)]
```

Then in GHC:

```
*Main> getEach 2 [1..10]
[10,8,6,4,2]
```