# Pairs of elements from list

Tags: haskell, clojure

I want to convert `[1,2,3,4]` to `[[1 2] [2 3] [3 4]]` or `[(1 2) (2 3) (3 4)]`. In clojure I have `(partition 2 1 [1,2,3,4])`. How can I do it in haskell? I suspect there is such function in standard api but I can't find it.

Comment: Why does clojure call this `partition`? If you partition something, you split in such a way that it's the sum of the parts.

Comment: Oh - found [clojure docs](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/partition) describing "partition n step coll: Returns a lazy sequence of lists of n items each, at offsets step
apart. If step is not supplied, defaults to n, i.e. the partitions
do not overlap."

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The standard trick for this is to `zip` the list with it's own `tail`:

```
> let xs = [1,2,3,4] in zip xs (tail xs)
[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)]
```

To see why this works, line up the list and its tail visually.

```
      xs = 1 : 2 : 3 : 4 : []
 tail xs = 2 : 3 : 4 : []
```

and note that `zip` is making a tuple out of each column.

There are two more subtle reasons why this always does the right thing:

- `zip` stops when either list runs out of elements. That makes sense here since we can't have an "incomplete pair" at the end and it also ensures that we get no pairs from a single element list.
- When `xs` is empty, one might expect `tail xs` to throw an exception. However, because `zip`
  checks its first argument first, when it sees that it's the empty list, the second argument
  is never evaluated.

Everything above also holds true for `zipWith`, so you can use the same method whenever you need to apply a function pairwise to adjacent elements.

For a generic solution like Clojure's `partition`, there is nothing in the standard libraries. However, you can try something like this:

```
partition' :: Int -> Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
partition' size offset
  | size <= 0   = error "partition': size must be positive"
  | offset <= 0 = error "partition': offset must be positive"
  | otherwise   = loop
  where
    loop :: [a] -> [[a]]
    loop xs = case splitAt size xs of
                -- If the second part is empty, we're at the end. But we might
                -- have gotten less than we asked for, hence the check.
                (ys, []) -> if length ys == size then [ys] else []
                (ys, _ ) -> ys : loop (drop offset xs)
```

Comment: so there is no generic function for it in a standard library? e.g. if want to have not tuples but triples or if i want to repeat or skip some values. just like http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/partition

Comment: @piotrek: Nothing in the standard libraries, no. However, it's not difficult to implement. I've added a sample implementation to my answer.

Comment: You can also replace `zip xs (tail xs)` with `zip <*> tail`, using `(->)`'s Applicative instance.

Answer (score 1):

Just to throw another answer out there using a different approach:

For n=2 you want to simply `zip` the list with its tail. For n=3 you want to zip the list with its tail and with the tail of its tail. This pattern continues further, so all we have to do is generalise it:

```
partition n = sequence . take n . iterate tail
```

But this only works for an offset of 1. To generalise the offsets we just have to look at the genrated list. It will always have the form:

```
[[1..something],[2..something+1],..]
```

So all left to do is select every `offset`th element and we should be fine. I shamelessy stole this version from @ertes from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599777/how-to-select-every-n-th-element-from-a-list):

```
everyNth :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
everyNth n = map head . takeWhile (not . null) . iterate (drop n)
```

The entire function now becomes:

```
partition size offset = everyNth offset . sequence . take size . iterate tail
```

Comment: Unfortunately your generalization gives some kind of weird permutation

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes is best to roll your own. Recursive functions are what gives LisP its power and appeal. Haskell tries to discourage them but too often a solution is best achieved with a recursive function. They are often quite simple as is this one to produce pairs.
Haskell pattern matching reduces code. This could easily be changed by changing only the pattern to (x:y:yys) to produce (a,b), (c,d), (e,f).

```
> prs (x:yys@(y:_)) = (x,y):prs yys
> prs "abcdefg"
[('a','b'),('b','c'),('c','d'),('d','e'),('e','f'),('f','g')
```