# Apply a Function to every element in a list

Tags: haskell

I've created a function `m` such that

```
m "abc" "def" == "bcd"
```

and I would like to create another function that uses `m` to generate the output `["bcd","efg","hia"]` when given the input `["abc","def","ghi"]`

The definition of `m` is

```
m :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
m str1 str2 = (drop 1 str1) ++ (take 1 str2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of [**`zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith) here where you take the entire list as first parameter, and `tail (cycle l)` as second parameter (with `l` the list):

```
combine :: [a] -> [a]
combine l = zipWith m l (tail (cycle l))
```

`zipWith` will enumerate concurrently on both lists and each time call `m` with an element of the first and the second list. For example:

```
Prelude> combine ["abc","def","ghi"]
["bcd","efg","hia"]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can append the first element to the end to simulate a wrap-around, then [zip the list with its tail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16762033/5923139) to get tuples of each element, then `map` it:

```hs
f :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
f [] = []
f l@(x:xs) = map (\(a, b) -> m a b) $ zip wrapped (tail wrapped)
    where wrapped = l ++ [x]
```

Alternatively, you can use [`uncurry`](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/uncurry_f.html):

```hs
f :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
f [] = []
f l@(x:xs) = map (uncurry m) $ zip wrapped (tail wrapped)
    where wrapped = l ++ [x]
```

Answer (score 3):

```hs
import Data.List.HT (rotate)
m2 :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
m2 list = zipWith m list (rotate 1 list)
```

where `m` is yours.

You can make it point free in a couple of ways.

Here's using the `Applicative` style,

```hs
m2 :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
m2 = zipWith m <$> id <*> (rotate 1)
```

which can read as *`m2` is the function that passes its argument to `id` and `rotate 1` respectively, and then those results to `zipWith m`*.

Here's using the `Monad`ic style,

```hs
import Control.Monad (ap)
m2 :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
m2 = zipWith m `ap` rotate 1
```

which is imho a bit less clear, in this case; you can read it as *`m2` passes its argument to both `zipWith m` and `rotate 1` and then feeds the result of the latter to the the result of the former*.

Honestly, I like [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65043246/5825294) a bit more, as it avoids importing `rotate` and gets the same effect with `tail . cycle`.