# Removing specific elements from lists in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

I'm having a hard time getting Haskell and functional programming together in my head. What I am trying to do is manipulate a string so that I am printing/returning specific characters each time based on a number given. For example:

```
printing "testing" 2 = "etn"

printing "testing" 3 = "sn"
```

I've read a lot online, and from what I understand I can achieve this with filtering and cycling, but I cannot get/understand the syntax of this language to get a working program.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026912/how-to-get-every-nth-element-of-an-infinite-list-in-haskell

Comment: `tnn s n  = [ c| (i,c)<- zip [1..] s, mod i n==0]` ;; `tnn "Testing" 2` >>> "etn" ;; `tnn "Testing" 3` >>> "sn" ;; `tnn "Testing" 1` >>> "Testing"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to describe my thought process so you can follow. This function fits the pattern of creating an output list (here a string) from an input seed (here a string) by repeated function application (here dropping some elements). Thus I choose an implementation with `Data.List.unfoldr`.

```
unfoldr :: (b -> Maybe (a, b)) -> b -> [a]
```

Okay so, I need to turn the seed `b` into (`Maybe`) an output `a` and the rest of the string. I'll call this subfunction `f` and pass it into `unfoldr`.

```
printing s n = unfoldr f s
  where f b = case drop n b of
                [] -> Nothing
                (x:xs) -> Just (x,xs)
```

It turns out that attempting to take the head off the front of the list and returning a `Maybe` is also a common pattern. It's `Data.List.uncons`, so

```
printing s n = unfoldr (uncons . drop n) s
```

Very smooth! So I test it out, and the output is wrong! Your specified output actually eg. for `n=2` selects every 2nd character, ie. drops `(n-1)` characters.

```
printing s n = unfoldr (uncons . drop (n-1)) s
```

I test it again and it matches the desired output. Phew!

Comment: It's funny, out of map, filter, and folder ... folder (and all of its types) was the one that I thought for certain I was not going to need to use. Thank you for thoroughly explaining the process though, this has helped me a lot

Comment: @WilliamJones It's definitely not necessary. `foldr` would be a bit of a strange choice (though I don't doubt it's possible), `unfoldr` is quite different (sort-of an inverse). You can straightforwardly do it by cycling / filtering eg. `printing s n = map fst . filter snd $ zip s (cycle (replicate (n-1) False ++ [True]))` but as you can see it's not quite as slick (do try to grok that definition too though). Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

To demonstrate the Haskell language some alternative solutions to the accepted answer.

Using **list comprehension**:

```
printing :: Int -> String -> String
printing j ls = [s | (i, s) <- zip [1 .. ] ls, mod i j == 0]
```

Using **recursion**:

```
printing' :: Int -> String -> String 
printing' n ls 
    | null ls'    = []
    | otherwise   = x : printing' n xs
    where
    ls'         = drop (n - 1) ls
    (x : xs)    = ls'
```

In both cases I flipped the arguments so it is easier to do partial application: `printing 5` for example is a new function and will give each 5th character when applied to a string.

Note with a minor modification they will work for any list

```
takeEvery :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
```

Comment: I considered making the same point (hah!) about argument order but couldn't express it convincingly. I may as well say, `printing "testing"` is also a function, from `n` to every `n`th character of "testing", so why is `printing n xs` any more natural of a formulation? But I do believe it, deeply!

Comment: I'd be tempted to avoid the `mod` using instead this variant: `[s | (i, s) <- zip (cycle [1 .. j]) ls, i == j]`

Comment: @A-Tayler I would say it is more likely to happen to users of the `printing` function. But both are fine and we always have `flip` so it is not much of a big deal.